# How to trim the spaces between xml tags and values using java

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have an xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

This is the actual XML file. In our application, we receive this xml as a String.

But somehow, due to hardware problems, the application is receiving the xml like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove+++</to>
<from>Jani+</from>
<heading>Reminder++++</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

In my java method I wrote code like  this,

```
//It will trim all the + in the xml.
if(xml.indexOf("[+]")!=-1)){
xml = xml.replaceAll("[+]","").trim();
}
```

This gave a result like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove  </to>
<from>Jani </from>
<heading>Reminder    </heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I again modified my code like this.

```
//It will replace all the + and white spaces in the xml.
if(xml.indexOf("[+]")!=-1)){
xml = xml.replaceAll("[+ ]","").trim();
}
```

But, this code is giving me a result like the following.

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>//here I lose the spaces. 
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Here I am losing the spaces in the `<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`.

The other part of the xml body is OK.

```
    <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
```

except this `<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>.`

When I am trying to run this in my application, I am getting SAXParcerException: Missing white spaces...etc.

How can I write my code exactly to get the file as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

My application is built on purely Jdk 1.4, web server as tomcat.

Comment: Your result doesn't make much sense. How about: `if (xml.contains("+")) { xml = xml.replaceAll("\\+","").trim(); }`?

Comment: I don't get it, You are trying fix wrong output which was generated by not your app? Cmon, there is no such thing like hardware problem generating additional chars :) You should investigate where is the problem and fix the cause, not the effect.

Comment: Thank you. But, The hardware problem, is not for all requests. The requests come to my application from user's cell phone. If 100 requests come to my application to handle, only 1 or 2 requests are getting this problem. Our client also told that this is related to phones which users are using... So, we are trying to fix it as application level. If the request having this problem of + then, we re trying to remove it. If the request is not contains +, the transactions are normal.

Comment: I again tried with if (xml.contains("+")) also. But, I don't know, If I write contains, eclipse workspace is showing errors. It is may be because of my application built with jdk 1.4 only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
if (xml.contains("+")) {
    xml = xml.replace("+", "");
}
```

instead of

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("[+ ]","").trim();
```

with jdk 1.4 you can use

```
if (xml.indexOf("+") != -1) {
    xml = xml.replace("+", "");
}
```

Comment: The replace(char oldChar, char newChar) method returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

Comment: But, My eclipse workspace is showing errors if I use contains. my application developed in  Jdk 1.4 only. give me any other way for this. and more over, I am new to java technology

Comment: You're right, the contains method was introduced into java in JDK 1.5. I added an jdk 1.4 example above

Answer (score 0):

Try with `xlm.replaceAll("\\++", "");` to replace one or more `+` with nothing at once.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. But, If I tried like this, the + is removed. But, the result is coming as <from>Jani  </from> like that. It is giving white spaces. which is again a problem for me.

Comment: @rajujwala whitespace? are you sure that you replace for empty string `""`, and not for space `" "`???

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove all `"+"` that appear before `"</"`,:

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("\\++<\", "<\");
```

This won't affect `"+"` appearing elsewhere, such as:

```
<tag>Bill + Ted+++</tag>
```

will become

```
<tag>Bill + Ted</tag>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I will try this replaceAll("\\++<\", "<\"). May be this will resolve my problem.